# set cookie for lightbox form

Tags: jquery, html, cookies, set

I have a form in html and jquery and I want to set cookie, how would I do that?

```
 {
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {   
         $('#back').fadeIn(1000);
     });
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#close-btn').click(function(){
             $('#popup').fadeOut("fast");
         });
     });    
 </script>

 <html>
     <body>
         <div id="popup">
             <div id="back">
                 <div id="right">
                     <div style="width:18px; height:19px;">
                         <img src="img/Close.png" width="18"  style="cursor:pointer;display:block; margin-  left:350px;margin-top:-2px;" onclick="document.getElementById('back').style.display='none';"/>
                     </div>   
                     <div id="login-box">
                         <form id="login" name="welcome" action="#" method="post">
                         <div id="c" >
                             <span style="font:B Mitra; font-size:24px; font-weight:bold; color:#000;padding- left:270px;position:relative;top:-40px;"> ایمیل</spam>      
                             <input name="username"  onfocus="if (this.value = 'آدرس ایمیل') { this.value=''; }"   onblur="if      (this.value == '') { this.value='آدرس ایمیل'; }" style="position:absolute; margin:-30px 0 0 60px; width:215px; height:25px; text-align:right; background:#ffffff; border:2px solid #0CF;border-radius:10px; color:#000; font:11px tahoma; left: -15px; top: 29px; border-radius:5px;" type="text"       value="آدرس ایمیل  "></div>                            
                         <div style="margin-top:35px;margin-left:120px;">
                             <input value="ارسال" name="submit" type="submit" style="background-color:#fcaf17;border-radius:5    px;   border:none; width:109px;height:35px;  font-family:tahoma; color:#FFF; font-size:18px;
font-weight:bold; ">
                         </div>
                         </form>
                  </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </body>
 </html>
}
```

Comment: When do you want to set cookie ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jQuery Cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to very easily set, read, and delete cookies.

```
// Set a cookie
$.cookie('foo', 'bar');

// Read a cookie
$.cookie('foo'); // returns bar

// Delete a cookie
$.removeCookie('foo');
```

Comment: thank you but i dont know how to use plugin, is it enough i write the codes you wrote?i want to show my form once a day for each user